# How to use PBFT as consensus protocol in Hyperledger fabric 1.0?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, consensus

How to use PBFT as consensus protocol in Hyperledger fabric 1.0?
What are the configurations required while setting up hyperledger fabric blockchain so that it uses PBFT as consensus algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

The only options for ordering service in Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 are:

- Solo orderer (mainly used for development and testing)
- Kafka based orderer (provides CFT agreement)

There is no option at the moment to enable PFBT on v1.0, there is plan in road map in couple of next releases to enable BFT based solution.